# On generalizing Gabor-Heisenberg uncertainty in a noisy environment

Tags: noise, snr, gabor, chirp

The Gabor-Heisenberg uncertainty represents the fundamental limit of time and frequency resolution one can extract from a signal.

$\sigma_t \sigma_f \geq \frac{1}{4\pi}$

My question is: what happen in a noisy environment?

If a bird sings a perfect constant pitch. Depending of the ambient noise, the frequency estimation of this pitch will be affected by the SNR.

Let say you have a time-varying arbitrary tune (like a bird song) played in a arbitrary colored noise environment. Is there a generalized Gabor uncertainty that takes to account the SNR?

I expected something like this:

$\sigma_t \sigma_f \geq function(SNR)$

Given the downvote(s) and the comments, I'll try to rephrase my question:

1. Frequency estimation is limited by SNR in a noisy environnent.
2. Frequency estimation is limited by Gabor-uncertainty.

If statements 1 and 2 are correct, how to reconcile the two statements in one general concept? I suppose, there should be a way to compute the *'frequency-estimation precision'* as a function of both SNR and time resolution (maybe with some other assumptions).

Comment: Wouldn't such a noise be additive? Let us say that the bird singing is $x$ and a white noise $n$ is present, then the resulting signal would simply be $y=x+n$. That is, the uncertainty $\sigma_t\sigma_f\geq \frac{1}{4\pi}$ Does not change but is applied to $y$, a signal with more frequencies. Does that answer your model?

Comment: +1 for havakok. SNR has nothing to do with achievable time-frequency resolution.

Comment: in signal processing, a signal isn’t a quantum mechanic quantity. It isn’t a fundamental limit. Model based algorithms often beat the Gabor limit. In noise, Cramer Rao bound, Weis weinstein bound, Ziv Zakai bound, ...

Comment: I think it's is not necessary to invoke QM when concidering the Gabor-Heisenberg uncertainty. This relationship is more general than QM.

Regarding the rest of your comment, is this limit beaten because information is added (a priori model)?

Comment: @pierebean there are no probabilities involved. no confidence regions, no p-value, no standard deviations. Nothing is uncertain. It’s a statement about how concentration in one domain effects the concentration is another.  In QM, it is a true uncertainty. In a noiseless deterministic signal, nothing is probabilistic.  There are no fundamental limits that can’t be exceeded.

Comment: So if the bird chirp is powerful enough (well above the noise), f(t) can be determined with arbitrary precision? I think not.
This problem is not quantum and yet, in my humble understanding, there seems to have a fundamental trade-off between how precise the frequency of the bird song is and when it occurs. 
If your time gate is short, then you the frequency will be ill-measured and if you time gate is long, well, your time resolution decreases.

Comment: @pierebean is a bird chirp a deterministic signal?  A rect function and the sinc function are Fourier pairs. What is your befuddlement?  What is uncertain?

Comment: I'll try to interpret your rhetorical answer.
Yes, a bird chirp is deterministic, physically speaking. Does that mean that I can plot f(t) with arbitrary precision? 

My befuddlement comes from the fact that when you plot a spectrogram, there seem to have fundamental resolution boxes (called Heisenberg boxes, again nothing quantum) which seems to represent fundamental limit to time of frequency resolution.

Comment: @pierebean. you can plot the instantaneous frequency of a linear FM chirp, which is a deterministic signal.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz Ok I see, terminology alert, I should have written "time-varying arbitrary tune" (no assumptions on the song sang by the bird) instead of chirp. I meant chirp in a general sense. Sorry.

Comment: @pierebean I can measure the start and stop times, and the frequency limits, to arbitrary precision. Again, statements about how concentrated in one domain manifests in another is not a probabilistic statement about uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

This uncertainty thing is often misapplied.  Your statement for #2 is such a misapplication.  The bell curve, aka Gaussian, is an eigenfunction of the FT, (only an approximation in the DFT, but that is a different story).  The uncertainty principle is saying when a shape is taken back and forth from the FT and the narrowest cluster of information is desired, this is accomplished by the Gaussian.  It has nothing to do with parameter estimation, but noise indeed does.

You are conflating different concepts.

My latest blog article gives the actual code for calculating the frequency, amplitude, and phase of a pure tone exactly in the single noiseless pure tone case.  It is also robust in the presence of noise.

[A Two Bin Solution](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1284.php)

Early on, when trying to show "experts" that I had found exact formula frequencies for tones in the DFT, I was often quoted what you said and they would refuse to even look at my math as if I were proposing a perpetual motion machine.

So many misconceptions exist about the DFT, even among supposed learned folks, and that is scary.

---

Don't believe me?

Here is an actual quote from an expert who shall remain unnamed.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
An "exact" computation of frequency based on FTs is not possible for
some very simple reasons:  The Fourier Transform is itself an
estimator, and the time-frequency uncertainty principle means
frequency can't be determined exactly without an infinitely long
observation window.  So essentially all frequency computations of time
series or signals are estimates, it's just that some are more accurate
or more efficient than others.

So claiming that you have an exact solution just isn't going to get
the attention of everyone interested in the field.
----------------------------------------------------------
```

The only truth in there is the last sentence.  So, I wrote it up in a blog where the math is indisputable and anyone who wants to can verify it for themselves.

No, I've never gotten an apology.

Comment: If you observe noiy data where your noise-free data follows a parametric model exactly and the mapping from model parameter to observations is unique (read: you made a sufficient number of observations), you can recover the model with a precision that is only limited by the amount of additive noise. Example: A sinusoid of unknown amplitude, phase, and frequency can be exactly recovered from 3 observations (provided they are close enough), 2 for a complex exponential. We teach that to our students in undergrad level. I'm surprised there are researchers in DSP that do not know this.

Comment: @Florian Determining the parameters from time domain points is not the same as recovering them from bin values.  It is in the latter, that the belief still exists it can't be done.  For time domain, what you say I don't think is generally disputed.  However your three time domain point example for sinusoids is flawed.  If you sample evenly so and the center point is at a zero crossing, the parameters are not recoverable.  Check these articles out:  https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1051.php  https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1056.php https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1074.php

Comment: It's absolutely the same since the mapping is linear. I could measure with any quite arbitrary functionals, and it doesn't matter if it's Fourier or a randomly drawn one. People in the Compressed Sensing community have been pushing on this for a good decade now (your problem is 1-sparse). As for the sampling, I said, the model needs to be uniquely recoverable. Of course this puts limits on where to place the sampling points. In general, close enough is fine. Hitting the zero crossing with one of them is a probability zero event if the parameters are assumed to live in a continuous space.

Comment: @Florian I'm not sure what you are saying.  Yes, the DFT is a linear transform, but the relationship between the tone parameters(except amp)and bin values are not.  I would say "I have an exact frequency formula".  They would say "It's impossible because of the uncertainty principle."  I would say, "That's not true, each bin value is a function of three real variables, with three bins (my original formula) I can form a set of three equations, three unknowns and solve for the unknowns.  They would reply, "The math around these issues are well known, refer to.." and send me off on a goose chase.

Comment: @Florian I should have clarified, the issue is really about having a closed form solution vs numerical methods.  That's what I meant by "exact equation".

Comment: Sure, I understand that. I'm just not surprised at all it exists.

Comment: @Florian  Neither am I.  What I was surprised about, and am puzzled by to this day, is the dogmatic concept that it can't exist.  And the arrogance I encountered among the "experts" proclaiming that it was "well known" that is couldn't exist and thus not worth looking at bristles me to this very day.  The arrogance wasn't as universal as the dogma, but close (particularly among IEEE members).  The first expert who recognized it, to my knowledge, was Vicanek who beat me to a two bin solution for the real case.  https://vicanek.de/articles/FreqFromTwoBins.pdf  He's a sharp dude.

Comment: Dear @CedronDawg and Florian, Thank you for your inputs.
1) So if I rephrase in simple terms what I have understood, since a sinewave could be determinist fitted with only 3 samples, only noise will prevent an accurate frequency estimation. However, I did not understand your argument about the relationship with parameter estimation and eigenfunctions. Could you provide a pedagogical text on the subject?

Comment: 2) Allow me to dig a bit further with my initial intuition. For a given noise power (fixed), everything thing else being equal, will your frequency estimation be affected by your sampling rate (aka your time resolution)? I’m still not convinced that a relationship between $\sigma_{freq}=f(\delta_{t})$ does not exist. But maybe naming this relationship “Gabor uncertainty” is wrong. Now if you change the local SNR, your $\sigma_{freq}$ will be affected. At the end, there should be a mathematical relationship in the form: $\sigma_{freq}=f(\delta_{t},SNR)$, no?

Comment: Not by the time resolution per se, but by the number of samples generally yes. As an example, for a single complex exponential, the maximum likelihood (ML) statistical estimate of its parameters is the maximum of the periodogram (magnitude of its DTFT squared). The more samples you have, the sharper the peak on the periodogram is, as you mentioned (also referred to as _aperture_). Naturally, it is easier to find the true maximum of a noisy peak if its sharper. Note that this was only an example, there can be better estimators than the ML, e.g. the one from Cedron Dawg.

Comment: @pierebean Simply do a search on "fourier transform gaussian", then add the word "eigenfunction", then add the word "heisenberg" and you should be able to find plenty of references, the scholarlyness of which you will have to judge.  If you check the comparison paper you can find on this page http://www.tsdconseil.fr/log/scriptscilab/festim/index-en.html (upper right), you will find the methods using Gaussian windows are inherently inaccurate.  This is usually explained by "their tails have been chopped off".

Answer (score -1):

The Gabor Heisenberg uncertainty principles apply only to a "noise free" world of continuous mathematical functions. The harvesting of information from noisy data is not part of these theories that were formulated ~ a century ago.

Comment: The principle is universal, noise doesn't change that. It doesn't make claims with respect to some "intended" input, only the input itself, whether noisy or not.